# How to rename dataframe columns with month year in R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, lubridate

I am reading xlsx which has some date columns names as

```
Name <- c("some data")
Date <- c("some data")
ID <- c("some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-01` <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-02`  <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-03` <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-04`  <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-05` <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-06`  <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-07` <- c( "some data")
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-08`  <- c( "some data")


df <- data.frame(
Name,
Date,
ID,
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-01`,
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-02`,
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-03`,
`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-04`)
```

I would **only** like to rename **All** the columns like `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-01` and write to new xlsx file.
what is the best way to achieve the end result below ?

Can i write a function like below to `strsplit` ?

```
function(df)
{
  temp <- (df)
  temp$`comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-01`<- strsplit(df)[[1]][2]
  return(temp) |> write.xlsx(new_df)
}
```

```
new_df

Name <- c("some data")
Date <- c("some data")
ID <- c("some data")
`2022-01` <- c( "some data")
`2022-02`  <- c( "some data")
`2022-03` <- c( "some data")
`2022-04`  <- c( "some data")
`2022-05` <- c( "some data")
`2022-06`  <- c( "some data")
`2022-07` <- c( "some data")
`2022-08`  <- c( "some data")
```

Comment: What you wrote was not valid R syntax. I tried surrounding all your invalid variable names with backticks which should be correct. If not, please fix. Check out the guide on how to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with functions like `dput()` to make sure what you share is valid R data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of examples of using `names<-` and regex sub functions on the existing names of hte dataframe:

```
 names(df) <- sub("comprehensive|\\(|\\)", "", names(df))
 df
#-----------------------
       Name      Date        ID ..Monthly..2022.01 ..Monthly..2022.02 ..Monthly..2022.03 ..Monthly..2022.04
1 some data some data some data          some data          some data          some data          some data
 names(df) <- sub("comprehensive|\\(|\\)|\\c", "", names(df))
#----------
 df
#-----------
       Name      Date        ID ..Monthly..2022.01 ..Monthly..2022.02 ..Monthly..2022.03 ..Monthly..2022.04
1 some data some data some data          some data          some data          some data          some data
#--------------

names(df) <- gsub("comprehensive|\\(|\\)|\\.", "", names(df)) # remove periods

df
#-------------
       Name      Date        ID Monthly202201 Monthly202202 Monthly202203 Monthly202204
1 some data some data some data     some data     some data     some data     some data
```

All of the special characters in an R regex pattern need to be double escaped.

See the list of special characters at:

```
?regex
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution: write a simple function and use `rename_with` with a selection-helper like `starts_with` or `contains`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# ----------------
my_data <- tibble(
  Name = c("some data"),
  Date = c("some data"),
  ID   = c("some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-01` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-02` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-03` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-04` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-05` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-06` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-07` = c( "some data"),
  `comprehensive (Monthly) 2022-08` = c( "some data"))

# ----------------
my_function <- \(x) str_extract(x, "\\d+.\\d+")
my_data <- rename_with(my_data, starts_with("Comprehensive"), my_function)

# ----------------
> glimpse(my_data)
Rows: 1
Columns: 11
$ Name      <chr> "some data"
$ Date      <chr> "some data"
$ ID        <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-01` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-02` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-03` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-04` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-05` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-06` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-07` <chr> "some data"
$ `2022-08` <chr> "some data"
```

Comment: Although I personally do not like a `{tidyverse}` suggestions, when OPs attempt to write vanilla R, why cluttering the environment? Put your `str_extract(...`  inside `rename_with()`

Comment: From my amateur point of view, better readability, specially with large regex patterns.